# Awk matching of entire record using regular expression

Tags: awk, gawk

Using Awk I want to match the *entire* record using a regular expression. By default the regular expression matching is for parts of a record.

The ideal solution would:

- Be general for all fields, regardless of the field separator used.
- Not treat the entire input as a single field and parse it manually using string functions.
- Work in a general way and not be specific to gawk for example.

However any and all solutions are of interest as long as they **use Awk without calls to external programs**.

An example, I have:

```
$ ls
indata.txt  t1.awk
$ cat indata.txt 
a1010_
1010_
1010_b
$ cat t1.awk 
/[01]*_[01]*/ { print $0 }
```

I get:

```
$ awk -f t1.awk indata.txt
a1010_
1010_
1010_b
```

This is the result I am seeking:

```
$ awk -f t1.awk indata.txt
1010_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add a beginning and end anchor to your regex:

```
/^[01]*_[01]*$/ { print $0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gawk '/^[01]*_[01]*$/' indata.txt
1010_
```

Comment: I know your answer is equal to Paul's. And I can't tell who was written first. I picked Paul's answer as my accepted by letting chance decide.

Comment: @Kent: Paul was the first to answer.

Comment: But it's not an identical answer. This one is much more awk-ish.